# Python Requests with Client Certificate

Tags: python, python-requests, client-certificates

I have a windows 11 machine and get the following error with my code:
CODE:

```
import requests
try:
  r = requests.post("https://example/api/v1",headers=pHeaders,json=data)  
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

ERROR:

```
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I understand this has something to do with the client cert being self signed, I have followed other stack overflow questions but it didn't resolve my issue. Can someone please walk me through the entire process of how to create a valid certificate, where to save it and how to use it with the Python **Requests Module**? It will also be helpful is someone can give me the same process, just for Linux as I need to implement this on a linux server in two weeks?

Comment: Answer already exists in official docs. Check [SSL Cert Verification](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), [Client Side Certificates](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates).

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks for the documentation, I have used cert=(pathToCert,pathToKey) and I got the same error. I also used certifi module to try and certify the certificates but I sill get the same error. Therefore I am not sure where I went wrong, and I'd like to understand the entire process, because maybe I took the wrong approach with creating the certificate or made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I understand the code that I need to implement. Could you maybe assist me with the steps on how to create a client certificate?

Comment: Do you control this server? If yes, you should have a SSL certificate on server side.

Comment: I have control of the device as it is my local device I am using to connect to the api (Windows machine). On the server that I am trying to connect to I uploaded a private and public key pair. Does this help with context?

Comment: Yes, it does. Have you tried to pass public key `public.pem` to `verify` argument?

Comment: I have 3 certificates:
1. Issuing CA
2. Root CA
3. <Certificate Name.crt>

And a key file:
- <Certificate Name.key>

Which one of these certs am I supposed to use? 
I used Cert No.3 and got the following error:
```raise IOError("Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, "
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path:```

Comment: Sorry, was kinda busy hiding in shelter. Your cert file should include all certificate chain, so if you have 3, add public keys of every cert into a file.

Comment: For example, [this](https://file.io/ktIPOzEzJVkZ) is cert chain for Stack Overflow.